# Google Natural Language Sentiment Analysis Aggregate Scores

Tags: nlp, google-cloud-platform, sentiment-analysis

In [this part](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/basics#entity_sentiment_analysis_responses) of the documentation of the Google Cloud Platform Natural Language API, it is described that

> *The overall score and magnitude values for an entity are an aggregate of the specific score and magnitude values for each mention of the entity.*

I can't figure out how this aggregation works. In the example provided in the documentation, Marvin Gaye has two mentions. One of the mentions has a sentiment of 0.4 and a magnitude of 0.4, the other mention has a score of -0.2 and a magnitude 0.2. The aggregate sentiment for Marvin Gaye is score 0.1 and magnitude 0.6.

I have tried other texts myself and can't figure out how the aggregation is made. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the length of the document, and how are you using some key words, i ran some tests and the results were all different except for a couple when i used a name of a famous person and didn't use any expression showing a emotion, because always got 0.
I can say that it's not an a sum of values, could be some weird operation using the values that is showed in the response.
About the Marvin Gaye example, the result is a mixed sentiment, because of the use of the emotions: "is the best" and "so sad".

Hope this helps with your research.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That might be the case. I however need to know more in detail how it is aggregated to be able to use the same aggregation method myself to get comparable results.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Google Cloud Platform Support and got this answer:

> *"The way the aggregation works is breaking down the input text into smaller components, often ngrams, which is likely why the documentation talks about aggregation, however, the aggregation isn't a simple addition, one can't sum individual sentiment values of each entity to get a total score."*

So it doesn't seem possible to give a simple explanation of exactly how the aggregation is made.