# Document Sentiment Magnitude != sum(Sentence Magnitude)

Tags: google-cloud-nl, magnitude

I am currently utilizing the google cloud NL api for some tests where I analyze news articles. I was initially curious about how document magnitude was calculated, and searches here yielded

[Google Cloud Natural Language API - How is document magnitude calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398253/google-cloud-natural-language-api-how-is-document-magnitude-calculated)

where it was mentioned to be the sum of constituent sentence magnitudes.

In my own tests, I have found that this was not the case. Is there any thing I might be doing wrong?

---

For clarity, I am using the running Python 3.7.3 in a conda environment with google-cloud-language obtained from conda-forge.

```py
document =types.Document(content = str, type = enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document)

sentence_sents = sentiment.sentences
test_mag = 0
for sent_obj in sentence_sents:
     test_mag += sent_obj.sentiment.magnitude

print(sentiment.document_sentiment.magnitude)
print(test_mag)
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example where this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From another thread it can be sometimes just the absolute sum but not always.

[Google Natural Language Sentiment Analysis Aggregate Scores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998973/google-natural-language-sentiment-analysis-aggregate-scores)

> "The way the aggregation works is breaking down the input text into smaller components, often ngrams, which is likely why the documentation talks about aggregation, however, the aggregation isn't a simple addition, one can't sum individual sentiment values of each entity to get a total score."

I assume this is the case for score and magnitude calculations.

Comment: Looking at this patent, it could be something related. A mix of signal processing and filtering/boosting absolute scores to reach their value.
[Signal processing approach to sentiment analysis for entities in documents](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8725494B2/en)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It didn't occur to me to check the patent